# Prove integral equals 1 in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \text{d}x=1$$ 
You are free to use the fact that for each $x\in[0,1]$ the sequence $\{(1+x/n)^n\}$ is monotone increasing and converges to $e^x$.

I'm not even sure where to begin. Please help walk me through this.

Comment: I'm wondering if one could instead integrate this directly and afterwards use the asymptotic properties of the $\Gamma$-Function...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Oh come on, it gives you a monotone sequence! Surely you want to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem? :)